# leaflet map does not recognize my array variable coming from a hiddenfieldvalue in code behind

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to show some gps point from sql server on a map.
i stored my dots in a hidden value using some code.

```
 string cs 

  =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select directionX,directionY from DailyReport where date='1397/10/20'", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                list.Add(reader["directionX"] +","+ reader["directionY"]);
                HiddenField1.Value= string.Join(",", list.ToArray());

            }
        }
```

after that I stored the hiddenfield value in a javascript variable:

```
 var arr1 = '<%=this.HiddenField1.Value%>';
```

but using the javascript code map doesnt show the polyline.

```
 <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
           var x = document.getElementById('<%= txtX.ClientID %>').value;
      var y = document.getElementById('<%= txtY.ClientID %>').value;
    function showRout() {
        //var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([29.6208701, 52.5779901], 16);

        //var x = 29.6208701;

        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([x, y], 16);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(mymap);

        var arr = [
    [29.6208701, 52.5779901],
        [29.6195714, 52.5765552],
         [29.6182244, 52.5752645]
        ];

        var arr1 = '<%=this.HiddenField1.Value%>';    
        alert("value from hiddenfield is : "+arr1 +"and array written by hand is: " +arr);
        var polyline = L.polyline(arr1).addTo(mymap);

    }
</script>
```

It is okay when I write a javascript array like this:

```
  var arr = [
    [29.6208701, 52.5779901],
        [29.6195714, 52.5765552],
         [29.6182244, 52.5752645]
        ];
```

I have checked the values comming from two variables 'arr' and 'arr1' using 'alert' function and they are the same.
I don't know how to use my hiddenfield value to show my polyline on the leaflet map.

Comment: You've got single quotes `'` around the assignment to `arr1`, This will assign a string rather than an array. They look the same in your  'alert' but they're not. Remove the single quotes.

Comment: @peeebeee Thank you . I replaced single quotes with [ ] and it works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final answer to assign hidden field to a Javascript array is

```
var arr1 = [<%=this.HiddenField1.Value%>];
```

You could perhaps look at rewriting the C# code to output JSON that will more easily drop into the Javascript world.